# Define two ranges and then join them

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently wondering on how to select as a range in VBA, ranges of values, and hope someone could assist on the below piece of code.

```
eoline = 50
first = 5
For i = 0 To eoline
multi = 2 * i + 1
a = Cells(first + 1, 1).Select
s1 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).select %select 1st range of values
b = Cells(first + 1, 2 * (i + 1)).Select
s2 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).select %select 2nd range of values
next i
```

Actually I'd like to select and copy s1 & s2, and I've unsuccessfully tried

```
myval = Union(s1, s2).select
selection.copy
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

1. Use `Set` when you create your ranges
2. Don't use `Select`.
3. When setting ranges look bottom up rather than selecting down (which will stop at a data gap if you have one)

*code*

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range

Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngCn2 As Long

lngCnt = 5
lngCnt2 = 2


Set rng1 = Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

Set rng1 = Range(Cells(lngCnt + 1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
Set rng2 = Range(Cells(lngCnt + 1, 2 * (lngCnt2 + 1)), Cells(Rows.Count, 2 * (lngCnt2 + 1)).End(xlUp))

Set rng3 = Union(rng1, rng2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, as it's always interesting to see another way of achieving the same task.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Here is the complete solution to my problem:

```
Dim s1, s2, myval As Range
eoline = 50
first = 5

multi = 2 * i + 1
a = Cells(first + 1, 1).Select
Set s1 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
b = Cells(first + 1, 2 * (i + 1)).Select
Set s2 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
Set myval = Union(s1, s2)
myval.Select
```

Comment: You should edit your question rather than posting a non answer.

Comment: sure. However to avoid creating confusion,  it's better to rely on this section  `post your own answer` and add some updates in the wake of findings since it could be beneficial to others. Here the update did work. Cheers